# Android dialog or floating activity off-center

Tags: android, layout, dialog

Is it possible to have an Android Alert box or Dialog off-center?  I have tried everything that comes to mind, including making a custom Dialog activity and theme (extending Android:Theme.Dialog), but I have not been able to move it from it's centered position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can make the background translucent and fill the entire view, then nest a visible layout within that you can use layout_gravity="top|left" on.

A little off topic, but if you just want to display text, an easier way is to use a toast.

```
Toast toast = new Toast(new ContextThemeWrapper(getApplicationContext(), R.style.YourDialogStyle));
toast.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.TOP, 0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`PopupWindow`? An example can be found here: http://www.anddev.org/how_to_create_a_popupwindow-t1259.html